# App compiled with IOS SDK 10 has edge protection ON by default on iphone X

Tags: ios, iphone-x

When compiling an app using IOS SDK 11, the edge protection on iphone X is turned OFF by default, like apple advises too.

But when i run my app compiled with a previous SDK (like 10 for example), the edge protection is ON by default, even if i haven't set it up (in fact i think theres no way to activate it in previous versions).

Is there a way i can set it OFF by default (using SDK <= 10) like apple recommends in their guidelines?

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the screenshot? What exactly your problem?

Comment: the problem is, when i compile the app with xcode 8.3.3 (using an older SDK), the app has the edge protection ON by default (maybe because compatibility mode?) when it should be OFF by default. when i compile it using xcode 9 the edge protection is off by default (like it should be according to apple). both running on iphone X.

Just want to make sure this is the default behavior by apple, or if theres something else going on.

Comment: If you want your app to display edge to edge in iPhone X you should add LaunchImage for iPhone X.

Comment: the problem is not displaying edge to edge, i already use a launch image that covers the entire screen. is the fact that "edge protect" is ON by default when compiling with xcode 8.3.3. edge protect is the feature that you have to swipe the home "button" twice for it to work instead of just once. apple recommends to leave it OFF, except when really needed. but when compiling with xcode 8.3.3 its ON by default, when compiling with xcode 9 its OFF by default (like it should be).